Total power generated by a 3 phase motor. Please check my working?
I'm driving a 3 phase motor with a turbine, and across each pair of terminals I have applied the same resistance, R.
I measure the root mean square potential difference, V_rms, across terminal 1 and 2 of the motor.
My question is, using V_rms and R, how can I work out the total power produced by the motor?
Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I'm not an electrical engineer and I want to check whether my working is correct. The total resistance across terminal 1 and 2 is R*2/3, so the electrical power across terminal 1 and 2 is V_rms^2/(R 2/3), so the total power is 3V_rms^2/(R 2/3). Is this correct?


Does this help you visualize it any better: -

Maybe another hint: the voltage across each resistor is the RMS voltage you measured (assuming the generator output is balanced).

Thanks that helps. I'm overthinking it. So 3 V_rms^2 / R ?

@PigeonBrain correct and well done. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
